# How can I create a fluctuating brightness scary / horror effect?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

Example: [LIMBO](http://youtu.be/t1vexQzA9Vk)

That example is very complex and the fluctuation is smooth, but I was wondering if anyone could suggest a good approach to creating this sort of effect using Java 2D? I was just about to start coding an image raster data manipulation algorithm but thought I might potentially save myself a lot of time to ask you guys first. The ideal result would be if I could just paint a fluctuating overlay on a glasspane.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it has all you need, but to avoid reinventing the wheel I'd suggest you to have a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/). It's generally used as a simple multimedia development environment, but its rich libraries can also be imported manually into a traditional Java project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JOGL or even something like [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) then you can specify fog. You can specify an exact composition of colors giving the right effect as well as where the fog will appear and how dense. Fluctuating the density with each game loop will give it that "pulsing" effect that  you are looking for.